# WooCommerce and Autoship Cloud - Limit the Autoship option by quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is a very specific problem, but we have the Autoship Cloud plugin installed on a WooCommerce site so we can offer both One-time Purchases and monthly autoship options. Our client only has 1 product available for autoship, and they want to limit customers to only being able to autoship 6 at a time.

I'm not very well-versed in coding, but I have it 99% of the way there with the following snippet in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'custom_total_item_quantity_message' );
function custom_total_item_quantity_message() {
    $max_count   = 6;
    $product_id = 275;
   $in_cart = false;
  
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
      $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];
      if ( $product_in_cart === $product_id ) $in_cart = true;
            $item = $cart_item['data'];

        if(!empty($item)) {
            $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
   }

    if( is_cart() && $in_cart && $quantity > $max_count ){
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-info">';
        printf( __("<style>.autoship-yes, .autoship-schedule-options .autoship-frequency.active{display: none !important;}</style>Sorry, Autoship is only available for 6 bottles or less.", "woocommerce"), $max_count - $quantity );
         wc_enqueue_js( "
         $('div.woocommerce').on('click', 'input.qty', function(){
          $('.autoship-no-radio').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.autoship-no-radio').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
        });
      " );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Basically, what the code is supposed to do is hide the "Autoship" radio button and automatically select the "One-time Purchase" radio button when more than 6 of the specific product (product ID=275) are added to the cart. The $(document).ready(function() script does fire properly when someone adds more than 6 to the cart from the beginning, but the $('div.woocommerce').on('click', 'input.qty', function() script does not work if less than 6 are added to the cart, then the user updates the quantity.

The code was working perfectly when it just listened for 6 items total in the cart, but after I added this portion:

```
    $product_id = 275;
   $in_cart = false;
  
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
      $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];
      if ( $product_in_cart === $product_id ) $in_cart = true;
            $item = $cart_item['data'];

        if(!empty($item)) {
            $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
   }
```

so it would only apply to that specific product, it stopped working.

To show exactly what's happening, it works fine with up to 6 items in the cart:
[image]

But once you tick the Quantity up to 7, the function itself works correctly, but the $('div.woocommerce').on('click', 'input.qty', function() script does not fire:
[image]

By contrast, when adding more than 6 of the product to the cart from the very beginning, the whole thing works as expected:
[image]

It's probably also worth mentioning that I have a function added that automatically updates the cart when the quantity or the autoship radio buttons are updated:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'bbloomer_cart_refresh_update_qty' ); 
 
function bbloomer_cart_refresh_update_qty() {
   if ( is_cart() || ( is_cart() && is_checkout() ) ) {
      wc_enqueue_js( "
         $('div.woocommerce').on('change', 'input, select', function(){
            $('[name=\'update_cart\']').trigger('click');
         });
      " );
   }
}
```